# Return dates from last/this week depending on the current time and when "production" started

Tags: sql-server, date, common-table-expression

Sorry if the Title is confusing but it's hard to explain what I'm after in one phrase.

I'm currently producing a report based on the production for the week.  I start off my CTE construction with the following to get the days Monday to Friday of the current week:

```
WITH
     cte_Date AS
     (
            SELECT
                   CAST(DateTime AS date) AS Date
            FROM
                   ( VALUES
                   (GETDATE()
                   )
                 , (DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()))
                 , (DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE()))
                 , (DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()))
                 , (DATEADD(day,-4,GETDATE()))
                 , (DATEADD(day,-5,GETDATE()))
                 , (DATEADD(day,-6,GETDATE())) ) AS LastSevenDays(DateTime)
            WHERE
                   DATENAME(weekday, DateTime) = 'Monday'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                   DATEADD(day,1,Date)
            FROM
                   cte_Date
            WHERE
                   DATENAME(weekday,Date) <> 'Friday'
     )
```

This is working fine.  I have made the report available to users so they can run it anytime however sometimes nobody is available to run it last thing Friday.  This means they don't get to see the full production for Friday and then the following week the CTE days change.

I'm trying to keep this a one-click affair so rather than introduce date parameters I proposed to the users that we adjust the query such that if they run the report before midday on "Monday" then it will show them last week's figures and they were happy with this (me and my big mouth).  I put Monday in quotes because what we really mean of course is the first *production* day of the week.

My primary data table (which we'll call MyData) has a datetime field named DateTime (really!) that I can reference to determine the first day of production for the week.

One final caveat:  Due to the layout of the report the users insisted that they always want to see the five days Monday to Friday, even if there is no production on a given day.  (Consequently I do a LEFT JOIN from cte_Date to all other tables required.)  So to be clear, right now as I'm typing this it's 11:45am local time on Tuesday and yesterday happened to be a public holiday here so running the report now should return Monday to Friday last week, but running it in 20 minutes time should return Monday to Friday this week.

Please help, my poor brain is getting twisted trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I came up with the most *efficient* approach, but after a week of tossing it about in my brain this is what I came up with.  I approached the problem from the opposite direction of that suggested by @ZLK.

My existing logic was already giving me the Monday of this week so in a subquery I looked for the first production record after Monday, stripped off the time with a DATEDIFF and made it midday with a DATEADD.  I was then able to compare the current Date/Time with midday of the first production day to determine whether to reduce the date by one week.

I replaced this SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DateTime AS date) AS Date
```

with this one:

```
SELECT -- Monday this week if it's after midday on the first production day otherwise Monday last week
        DATEADD(week,IIF(GETDATE()>=DATEADD(hour,12,(
                                                        SELECT DATEDIFF(day,0,MIN(DateTime)) 
                                                        FROM MyData 
                                                        WHERE CAST(MyData.DateTime AS date) >= CAST(LastSevenDays.DateTime AS date) 
                                                    )),0,-1),CAST(LastSevenDays.DateTime AS date)) AS Date
```

To cater for the case where a new week has commenced but the operator runs the report before production starts I carefully arranged the boolean condition inside my IIF clause so that the empty result set from the subquery would mean the test returned FALSE and the operator would still see last week's figures.

(@ZLK, Thanks for your input - you did help my thinking a bit but I don't think your answer should be marked as correct.  What I've come up with here is what I was originally requesting and didn't require the use of a static table.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can tackle this, but they all boil down to the same thing: you need a way of figuring out whether it's before or after 12pm on the first working day of the current week, then you need to get the Monday of the current "production week".

Let's just say, for simplicity's sake, you have some sort of table that contains public holidays (or non-production days). To find out whether it's the first day of the current production week, you basically just have to add the number of days in a row since the start of the week that have been public holidays.

Then you need to figure out whether it's before or after 12pm of that day.

If it's before you want last week's Monday-Friday. If it's after, you want this week's Monday-Friday.

Here's one way you might do this:

```
DECLARE @NonProductionDays TABLE (NPD DATE UNIQUE NOT NULL); -- Public holiday table. 
INSERT @NonProductionDays (NPD) VALUES ('2017-09-25');


DECLARE @i INT = -- You don't need a variable for this, but just to keep things simple...
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) -- Extract number of public holidays in a row this week before current date. 
    FROM @NonProductionDays AS N
    WHERE DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, N.NPD) = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE())
    AND N.NPD <= GETDATE()
    AND (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, N.NPD) = 'Monday' OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @NonProductionDays AS N2 WHERE N2.NPD = DATEADD(DAY, -1, N.NPD)))
);
SELECT D = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, T.N, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(HOUR, DATEADD(DAY, @i, '1900-01-01 12:00:00'), GETDATE()) / 24 / 7, '1900-01-01')) AS DATE)
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS T(N);

/*
    Breaking this down: 
        X = DATEADD(DAY, @i, '1900-01-01 12:00:00') 
            -- Adds the number of NPD days this week to '1900-01-01 12:00:00'
            -- So, for example, X would be '1900-01-02 12:00:00' this week
        Y = DATEDIFF(HOUR, X, GETDATE()) / 24 / 7 
            -- The number of weeks between X and now, by taking the number of hours and dividing by 24 then by 7 
            -- The division is necessary to compare the hour. 
            -- So, for example, as of 11am on the September 26 2017, you'd get 6142.
            -- As of 12pm on September 26 2017, you'd get 6143.
        Z = DATEADD(WEEK, Y, '1900-01-01')
            -- Just adds Y weeks to 1900-01-01, which was a Monday. This tells you the Monday of the current "production week".
            -- So, for example, as of 11am on September 26 2017, you'd get '2017-09-18 00:00:00.000'.
            -- As of 12pm on September 26 2017, you'd get '2017-09-25 00:00:00.000'.

        Then we cast this as a date and add 0/1/2/3/4 days to it to get Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday of the current "production week".
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @ZLK for your detailed answer.  Honestly though it's not what I was hoping for.  Sometimes non-production days are sporadic because they occur for reasons other than just public holidays, e.g. a major breakdown or even poor market conditions.  

That said, I agree totally with your first paragraph and perhaps I can springboard off that to enhance my original CTE.

Comment: @WayneIvory Regardless of whether it's public holidays or not, I think it's helpful to have some sort of "non-production day" table, or a dates table that, say, has every working day for the next hundred or so years and you take out the "non-production days" from it whenever one occurs. In any case, someone would manually need to update _something_ in the case of a sporadic non-production day or how would any sort of report know not to include that day?